# Extract the text from `p` within `div` with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am very new to web-scraping with Python, and I am really having a hard time with extracting nested text from within HTML (`p` within `div`, to be exact). Here is what I got so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

url = urllib.urlopen('http://meinparlament.diepresse.com/')
content = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
```

This works fine:

```
links=soup.findAll('a',{'title':'zur Antwort'})
for link in links:
    print(link['href'])
```

This extraction works fine:

```
table = soup.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"content-question"})
for x in table:
    print(x)
```

This is the output:

```
<div class="content-question">
<p>[...] Die Verhandlungen über die mögliche Visabefreiung für    
türkische Staatsbürger per Ende Ju...
<a href="http://meinparlament.diepresse.com/frage/10144/" title="zur 
Antwort">mehr »</a>
</p>
</div>
```

Now, I want to extract the text within `p` and `/p`. This is the code I use:

```
table = soup.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"content-question"})
for x in table:
    print(x['p'])
```

However, Python raises a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following code finds and prints the text of each `p` element in the `div`'s with the `class` "content-question"

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

url = urllib.urlopen('http://meinparlament.diepresse.com/')
content = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

table = soup.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"content-question"})
for x in table:
    print x.find('p').text

# Another way to retrieve tables:
# table = soup.select('div[class="content-question"]')
```

The following is the printed text of the first `p` element in `table`:

[...] Die Verhandlungen über die mögliche Visabefreiung für türkische Staatsbürger per Ende Juni sind noch nicht abgeschlossen, sodass nicht mit Sicherheit gesagt werden kann, ob es zu diesem Zeitpunkt bereits zu einer Visabefreiung kommt. Auch die genauen Modalitäten einer solchen Visaliberalisierung sind noch nicht ausverhandelt. Prinzipiell ist es jedoch so, dass Visaerleichterungen bzw. -liberalisierungen eine Frage von Reziprozität sind, d.h. dass diese für beide Staaten gelten müssten. [...]

Comment: This solution assumes that the HTML used on the page properly encloses all paragraphs in "p" element pairs. But this is often not the case, sometimes empy p elements are used to split the text, sometimes there is initial text, followed by spans of paragraphs, followed by trailing text, where the initial or trailing text is not enclosed in their own paragraph span etc. The solution above will only return the text enclosed by a pair of opening/closing p elements, but not the text  in between. Any way to get everything?

Comment: hi there Philip - i run this code on MX-Linux in ATOM but unfortunatly i get absolute no results  - any idea!?