# How to extract deeply nested <p> tags using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the content below and I am trying to understand how to extract the `<p>` tag copy using Beautiful Soup (I am open to other methods). As you can see the `<p>` tags are not both nested inside the same `<div>`. I gave it a shot with the following [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730372/extract-the-text-from-p-within-div-with-beautifulsoup) but that only seems to work when both `<p>` tags are within the same container.

```
<div class="top-panel">
  <div class="inside-panel-0">
    <h1 class="h1-title">Some Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="inside-panel-0">
    <div class="inside-panel-1">
      <p> I want to extract this copy</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inside-panel-1">
      <p>I want to extract this copy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As p tags are inside `div class="inside-panel-1`, so we can easily grab them by calling find_all method as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="top-panel">        
 <div class="inside-panel-0">  
  <h1 class="h1-title">        
   Some Title
  </h1>
 </div>
 <div class="inside-panel-0">  
  <div class="inside-panel-1"> 
   <p>
    I want to extract this copy
   </p>
  </div>
  <div class="inside-panel-1"> 
   <p>
    I want to extract this copy
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
# print(soup.prettify())

p_tags = soup.select('div.top-panel div[class="inside-panel-1"]')
for p_tag in p_tags:
    print(p_tag.get_text(strip=True))
```

Output:

```
I want to extract this copy
I want to extract this copy
```

Comment: Would there be a way to grab the `<p>` tags from class `top-panel`? The page will include various instances of `inside-panel-1` and I don't need all of them, just the ones from `top-panel`.

Comment: @Freddy, I've updated using css selectors. You can try this. Thanks

Comment: It also works. p_tags = soup.select('div.top-panel div[class="inside-panel-1"]>p')

Comment: Fazlul, I was able to follow your example and simplify a bit more by using the following `soup.select("div.top-panel p")` - ([CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)). Thank you for this.

Answer (score 4):

IIUC try

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="top-panel">
  <div class="inside-panel-0">
    <h1 class="h1-title">Some Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="inside-panel-0">
    <div class="inside-panel-1">
      <p> I want to extract this copy</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inside-panel-1">
      <p>I want to extract this copy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
# find all the p tags that have a parent class of inside-panel-1
soup.findAll({'p': {'class': 'inside-panel-1'}})

[<p> I want to extract this copy</p>, <p>I want to extract this copy</p>]
```

If you want just the text then try

```
p_tags = soup.findAll({'p': {'class': 'inside-panel-1'}})
[elm.text for elm in p_tags]  
# -> [' I want to extract this copy', 'I want to extract this copy']
```

Comment: After examining the provided solutions and in thinking more about my dilemma, the page will include many classes of `inside-panel-1` is there a way to grab the `<p>` tags from class `top-panel` in this case?